# Populate select box with DATE RANGE from MySQL

Tags: php

I have a table with two dates a start date and an end date. What I can't figure out is how to populate a select box with all dates from the start date to the end date inclusive.

My code is

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `eventStart` `eventEnd` FROM $tbl_events WHERE eventName = '$eventID'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
}
$stmt->close();
```

It works but it only populates the first date; I've searched the web, but can't find a solution to my issue.

Comment: @Vladimir Ramik thank you...can you please explain how I integrate this with my mysql select statement? Cheers

Comment: Your select may be returning only one result. I would run a raw query to get all the appropriate dates you desire and once you're satisfied, convert the query to incorporate your $eventID and ensure it returns you all those options in the array format/other format before looping through them. Can you post a sample return output with the WHERE conditional and without?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // $aResults = $stmt->fetch_all(); or $stmp->fetch_array();
    // Ensure your results look great to your liking before continuing.
    $aResults = array( 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006 );
    $iCountResults = count( $aResults );
    echo "<select>";

    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountResults; ++$i )
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $aResults[ $i ] . '">' . $aResults[ $i ] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
// $stmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$startdate_options = array();
$enddate_options = array();

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `eventStart` `eventEnd` FROM $tbl_events WHERE eventName = '$eventID'");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($startdate_val, $enddate_val);

while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $startdate_options[] = $startdate_val;
    $enddate_options[] = $enddate_val;
}

$stmt->close();

// from this point it really should be in another file

// startdate values render
echo '<select name="startdate" class="startdate">';
foreach ($startdate_options as $startdate)
{
    echo "<option value='$startdate'>$startdate</option>";
}
echo '</select>';

//enddate values render
echo '<select name="enddate" class="enddate">';
foreach ($enddate_options as $enddate)
{
    echo "<option value='$enddate'>$enddate</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

// Also please note, this is not very MVC, for sake of readability you really shouldn't do SQL statements, business logic and rendering html in the same source file or same class or same program flow. Actually you should only pass your "template engine" the $startdate_options and the $enddate_options arrays (and more like as a return value or as a class member than as a global variable)

Hope I could help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is great, but it puts the start date in one select and the end date in one select. Is it possible to have all dates in the same select?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood the task then.

In that case remove the following four lines (6th from bottom and 3 more lines upwards):
___
    echo '</select>';

    //enddate values render
    echo '<select name="enddate" class="enddate">';

___ You may also want to rename the variables in this case